# JavaFx media bytes

Tags: javafx, byte, mp3, media

I want to create a soundwave in my java programm from an mp3 file. I researched and found out, that for wav-files I need to use the AudioInputStream and calculate an byte array... From mp3-File I am using JavaFX media and media-player. Are the bytes from the Inputstream the same like from the Javafx media.getSource().getBytes(); ? An AudioInputStream cant read mp3...

Or how am I supposed to get the values for an mp3 file for soundwave?

Byte from AudioInputStream:

```
AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
        try {
            audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(next);

            int frameLength = (int) audioInputStream.getFrameLength();
            int frameSize = (int) audioInputStream.getFormat().getFrameSize();

            byte[] bytes = new byte[frameLength * frameSize];

            g2.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            for(int p = 0; p < bytes.length; p++){
                g2.fillRect(20 + (p * 3), 50, 2, bytes[p]);
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And from JavaFX:

```
Media media;
MediaPlayer player;

media = new Media("blablafile");
player = new Mediaplayer(media);

byte[] bytes = media.getSource().getBytes();
```

Answer (score 1):

The JavaFX Media API does not provide much low-level support as of Java 10. It seems to be designed with only the necessary features to play media, not manipulate it significantly.

That being said, you might want to look at [`AudioSpectrumListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/media/AudioSpectrumListener.html). I can't promise it will give you what you want (I'm not familiar with computer-audio concepts) but it may allow  you to create your sound-wave; at least a crude representation.

You use an `AudioSpectrumListener` with a [`MediaPlayer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html) using the corresponding [property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#audioSpectrumListenerProperty).

---

If your calculations don't have to be in real time then you can do them ahead of time using:

```
byte[] bytes = URI.create(media.getSource()).toURL().openStream().readAllBytes();
```

Note that if the media is remote, however, that you will end up downloading the bytes *twice*; once to get the bytes for your sound-wave and again when actually playing the media with a `MediaPlayer`.

Also, you'll want to do the above on a background thread and not the JavaFX Application thread to avoid the possibility of freezing the UI.